# Why won't my CSS class apply to <p> or <span> tags?

Tags: css

Why doesn't the 'test' class apply on usage at both the `<p>` tag and the `<span>` tag?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />   
        <title>Newsletter template</title>
        <!--general stylesheet-->
        <style type="text/css">
            p { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            a {
                color: #455670; text-decoration: underline;
            }
            test {
                margin: 20; font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #666666; line-height: 15px !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="test"><span class="test"> Check the spelling of the words you typed.</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

use `.test`. `test` is an element selector.

Comment: Cheers, what is an "element selector"?

Comment: element selectors are used to describe elements in the DOM tree by their name. If you had <test>content</test> in the html this would be represented by an element in the DOM tree with the name test. So you would use $('test') to instruct jQuery to select this element. If you have <div class="test">content</div> then $('test') will not select this element because its name is 'div', not test. But if you write $('.test') (notice the dot) this will tell jQuery that you want it to find all elements that have class 'test'. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

Because it should be `.test`, since it's a class, not just `test`.

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, to select an element by its class, you need to prefix the classname with a `.` As you have it,

```
test {
    margin: 20;...
}
```

expects to see an HTML element named `test` -- but there is no such element. Change your selector to

```
.test { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a period before the class name in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have feedback on the site, use the **meta** menu option at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Steve, SO is awesome as it is though!

Answer (score 1):

use .test instead of test in style.  use  **0px** in padding,margin instead of 0. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />   
            <title>Newsletter template</title>
            <!--general stylesheet-->
            <style type="text/css">
                p { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
                a {
                    color: #455670; text-decoration: underline;
                }
                .test {
                    margin: 20px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #666666; line-height: 15px !important;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class="test"><span class="test"> Check the spelling of the words you typed.</span></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 0 is fine, you dont need to add the Measurement for `px`, `em`, `in`, `cm`, `%` etc. if it is 0.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate all the tips SO users provide, since I haven't been formally educated in HTML/CSS in the slightest way.